# Update view not working? Django

Tags: python, django, url-routing

The users are able to create an aircraft post at this url:

```
url(r'^upload/aircraft/$', aircraft_create, name="aircraft_create"),
```

I've created a summary page where all of the users posts are displayed. They're able to edit and delete their posts here. The url:

```
url(r'^account/uploads/$', upload_overview, name="account_uploads"),
```

However, I want the user to be able to edit their posts on their summary page. The way I got it set it now, is that they can edit at `upload/aircraft/edit`, but I want to to be `account/uploads/edit`.

I've set it up like that but it's not doing anything? Any clues as to what it might be?

**Aircraft/views.py**

```
def aircraft_create(request):
  form = aircraft_form(request.POST or None)
  if form.is_valid():
    instance = form.save(commit=False)
    instance.user = request.user
    instance.save()
    messages.success(request, "Your upload has been successfully added!")
    return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())
  else:
    messages.error(request, "There seems to be something wrong. Have a look again..!")
  context = {"form":form,}
  return render(request,'aircraft/aircraft_form.html', context)
```

**Update view**

```
def aircraft_update(request, id=None):
  aircraft = get_object_or_404(Aircraft, id=id)
  form = aircraft_form(request.POST or None, instance=aircraft)
  if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
    messages.success(request, "Your edit has been successfully been saved!")
    return HttpResponseRedirect(aircraft.get_absolute_url())

  return render(request,'aircraft/aircraft_form.html',
    {"aircraft": aircraft, "form": form})
```

**Template**

```
  {% if UploadedAircraft %}
  {% for upload in UploadedAircraft %}
    <div class="col-lg-offset-0 col-md-4 col-sm-3 item">
        <div class="box"><a href="{{ upload.get_absolute_url }}"><img src="{{ upload.image.url }}" width="200px" height="200px" alt="{{ upload.title }}"/></a>
            <h3 class="name"><a href="{{ upload.get_absolute_url }}">{{ upload.name }}</a></h3>
            <a href="{% url 'aircraft_update' %}"><button class="btn">Edit</button></a>
            <a href="{% url 'aircraft_delete' %}"><button class="btn">Delete</button></a>
        </div>
```

**Summary page view**

```
def upload_overview(request):
    uploaded_aircraft = Aircraft.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    return render(request,'account/upload_overview.html',{'UploadedAircraft':uploaded_aircraft)
```

**url.py**

```
   #aircraft/detail/1
    url('^aircraft/detail/(?P<id>\d+)/$', aircraft_detail, name='aircraft_detail'),

    #account/uploads (Display Users uploads)
    url(r'^account/uploads/$', upload_overview, name="account_uploads"),

    #upload/aircraft (Create Aircraft)
    url(r'^upload/aircraft/$', aircraft_create, name="aircraft_create"),

    #Edit/aircraft
    url('^account/uploads/$', aircraft_update, name='aircraft_update'),
```

**EDIT**

```
def airline_update(request, id=None):
  airline = get_object_or_404(Airline, id=id)
  form = airline_form(request.POST or None, instance=airline)
  if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(airline.get_absolute_url())
  return render(request,'airline/airline_form.html',
    {"airline": airline, "form": form})
```

**Url**

```
#account/upload/edit/ (Edit airline)
url(r'^account/uploads/edit/(?P<id>[0-9]+)$', airline_update, name='airline_update'),
```

**Template**

```
<a href="{% url 'airline_update' id=upload.id %}"><button class="btn">Edit</button></a>
```

Comment: If you want them to be able to edit at the URL `/account/uploads/edit`, you would need to modify your last url to:  `url('^account/uploads/edit/$', aircraft_update, name='aircraft_update'),` ... currently you have nothing to match the URL  `/account/uploads/edit`

Comment: Page not found (404) No Aircraft matches the given query.

Comment: Can you update your post with your view definition for `aircraft_update`?

Comment: Yes, but not with the url I want. Have a look at my update view

Comment: Thank you for the update-- I have added an answer to try to address the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're trying to edit an aircraft with a specific ID, you would need something like this in url.py (assuming that the IDs are integers):

`url('^account/uploads/edit/(?P<id>[0-9]+)$', aircraft_update, name='aircraft_update')`

And in your template you would need to update your anchor link to include the ID:

`<a href="{% url 'aircraft_update' id=upload.id %}">`

NOTE that this assumes that the `upload` object (in your template's loop) includes an `id` property, and that the `id` property corresponds to the aircraft ID that you want to update. (It is possible that you have named this property something else.)

EDIT: This would be sufficient for executing a GET request. However, I notice that your view definition for `aircraft_update` also attempts to check whether a form is valid. Where is this form in your template? It does not appear to be in your loop.

Comment: Perfect. You're awesome!

Comment: I am glad I could help! I did include an edit to my post just now because I did not see any form defined in your template, but it's possible that you simply did not include that code for brevity's sake. If my post addressed your issue, please feel free to ignore my edit.

Comment: I have an airline model which is exactly the same as the aircraft model; same views - everything! I used the code above for the airline one and I get "No Aircraft matches the given query."

Comment: Are you sure you are querying the correct model? If you have a different model, `Airline`, I would not expect the Django error message to say "No *Aircraft* matches the given query". You should ensure your code is `get_object_or_404(Airline, id=id)`, assuming that your model name is indeed `Airline`

Comment: Check edits! It's all correct but throwing that error :/

Comment: The problem is that you now have two URLs defined with exactly the same path definition. Probably, the one that calls `aircraft_update` is defined first, so even though you want to update an airline, the `aircraft_update` method is invoked. You need to change your URL to something else, like `url(r'^account/airlines/edit/(?P<id>[0-9]+)$', airline_update, name='airline_update'),` ... the specific URL doesn't matter that much as long as it differs from an existing URL.

Comment: Thank you boss. You're honestly amazing!